# Business logic in JSF based app

Tags: jsf-2

Where should I put the logic of my app when i'm using JSF framework? As I understand managed beans are used only for getting/setting the properties of the form and also have controllers methods. I don't think that implementing the logic in controllers method is a good way. Of course I can use ejb to implement the logic and inject it to managed beans, but how it will work on servers that don't have an ejb container(e.g. Tomcat).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *I don't think that implementing the logic in controllers method is a good way.*

Indeed. Use business services like EJBs.

> *Of course I can use ejb to implement the logic and inject it to managed beans, but how it will work on servers that don't have an ejb container(e.g. Tomcat).*

You could use [OpenEJB](http://openejb.apache.org/3.0/tomcat.html) to enrich it with (limited) EJB 3.x capabilities. An alternative is [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/about), that's what they used during the EJB 2.x era when EJBs were hated.